# Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation

Tags: evaluation

This is my very first day using Mathematica, so please forgive me my complete ignorance...

I fear that this might be one of those questions that gets rejected for being "easily found in the documentation"... 
Nevertheless, searching hard and long through the documentation all that I may, I completely fail to find an answer to my - no doubt obvious - mistake...

I tried to define a function x[t_] and a function y[t_], both as it seems successfully...

I then tried to put them together in a complex valued function f[t_], which I believed to be an operation that could not possibly go wrong...

However to my surprise I keep getting a "Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of f[0]" error...

I really fail to see where this "recursion" could possibly come from...

Could anyone please put this noobie on the right track?

```
a = 2
(* 2 *)

T = 2^(3/2)
(* 2 Sqrt[2] *)

x[t_] = a Cos[2 Pi t/T] - Cos[2 Pi t]
(* -Cos[2 π t] + 2 Cos[(π t)/Sqrt[2]] *)

y[t_] = a Sin[2 Pi t/T] - Sin[2 Pi t]
(* -Sin[2 π t] + 2 Sin[(π t)/Sqrt[2]] *)

f[t_] = x[t] + I y[t]

During evaluation of In[112]:= $RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of f[0]. >>
During evaluation of In[112]:= Set::write: Tag Hold in Hold[f[0]] is Protected. >>

(* -Cos[2 π t] + 2 Cos[(π t)/Sqrt[2]] + 
    I (-Sin[2 π t] + 2 Sin[(π t)/Sqrt[2]]) *)

f[0]

During evaluation of In[113]:= $RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of f[0]. >>

(* Hold[f[0]] *)
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: I think you want to do your assignments with f[t_] :=   (note the extra colon, "delayed assignment").   I don't see the recursion here either, but if you have done a bunch of trial-and-errors, then you may have some definitions left over that cause the recurrence.  Simply quit the kernel (or mathematica) and start again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So much wrong there...

```
a = 2;
tx = 2^(3/2);
x[t_] := a Cos[2 Pi t/tx] - Cos[2 Pi t];
y[t_] := a Sin[2 Pi t/tx] - Sin[2 Pi t];
f[t_] := x[t] + I y[t];

f[20]

(* -1 + 2 Cos[10 Sqrt[2] π] + 2 I Sin[10 Sqrt[2] π] *)
```

*Don't* use uppercase initials for your symbols - you might clash with built-ins.

*Don't* use some external user-defined global symbol inside a definition in the manner you have unless there's a good reason to do so (I left that as is, but it's bad practice).

Read the documentation, learn the difference between `Set` (`=`) and `SetDelayed` (`:=`).

Read [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users) on this very site. Great resource for new users.

Go through the tutorials in the *Mathematica* documentation. Very worthwhile.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. And thanks for the tips!